# How to read object in subscribe (observable) -angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, observable, subscribe

I'm working on a project in angular 6 and i'm facing to a problem !
I want to read the content of an object which is in my observable  like this:

```
this.myService.getOne().subscribe(e => {
  this.e = e;
  console.log(this.e);
  console.log(this.e.id); // result => undefined
});
```

I can see **this.e** which look like that:

```
{"id":"1", "name":"myName", ...}
```

But **this.e.id** is *'undefined'*, same thing when i write **this.e['id']**.

Did you have any idea ?

Comment: console gives the correct output?

Comment: For the e, i see the entire object in the console but for e.id, i see 'undefined' whereas i can see 'id' into e

Comment: By naming of' getAll(); I would assume you are getting and array so maybe e[0].id would do the trick. But until we see what your actual response you get this is just a guess.

Comment: Sorry Bruno, i wanted to write 'getOne()', i just have an object in the output

Comment: Can you create a small stackblitz for this? It seems a rather unusual behaviour.

Comment: I made a stackblitz of this: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyz5oi), and `e.id` is working - Can you see any difference between your code and mine?

Comment: {"id":"1", "name":"myName", ...} looks like a json string not a javascript object. Try to JSON.parse(e)

Comment: @gyc It said that e is not defined

Comment: @Lasse my service is, not the same, i'm returning an observable of my object
i am using http.get(url)

Comment: how can e be undefined since you're logging it?

Comment: This is why i'm trouble :/

Comment: like this `return this.http.get<YourObject>(url)`? or are you not defining an object?

Comment: @Lasse, yes like this :)

Comment: The code as you show us should work (except for the json string that is returned from the service and that you have to parse). If you cannot reproduce the problem in a stackblitz, then problem comes from somewhere else you're not showing us.

Comment: Maybe into my Service ?

Comment: I have updated the [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyz5oi) to use http, and it is still working, so as @gyc says the problem must be somewhere else in your code

Comment: I've just seen that, i will look at your code with mine and try to fix the problem. I will put the answer after that, thanks to all ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the problem, i had 2 things in more into my getOne() method:

I changed the method from

```
getOne(): Observable<myObject> {...}
```

to

```
getOne() {...}
```

I changed the return from

```
this.get<myObject>(url, httpOptions); //httpOptions contained headers and response type 'text' as 'json'
```

to

```
this.get<myObject>(url);
```

Now its functional, thank you for your help ! :)